# any free service to use as HTML5 offline cache link?

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox, html5-audio

I tried using Dropbox links in my cache manifest, but it didn't work.

I tried NOT using cache manifest and simply:

```
<audio src="dropbox url" autoplay="true"></audio>
```

It doesn't play the sound either.  If I point `src` to a file within the project or on the hard disk, it works. Are there any free services for hosting such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any free and legal services for hosting audio content.  I'd recommend looking into cloud-based storage options (AWS S3, Rackspace Cloud Files, et cetera).  They typically have a cost based on the amount of files you have stored and the amount of data transfer per month.

You should be able to [use external URLs in your cache manifest](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/).  However, it may be possible the URL you're trying to use has response headers that prevent it from being used in such a way.

Comment: may i know why the response headers are giving such problems?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a URL that I can try this against and see why.  If you have Firebug installed in Firefox you could look and see what Response Headers are coming with the Dropbox URL (or if it's even being requested).

Answer (score -1):

You mean something simple and **FREE** that provides *100gb storage and 100gb traffic with ftp-access*?
See sites like http://www.100gb.co/. There are a lot more of those kind of services, just USE GOOGLE! Think about it.. what kind of $%^&* would pay anno 2012 ?!?

You could also use services like sound-cloud. The main difference is that you don't link to the bare *.mp3 file anymore, but to a flash file.

Warning: just make sure you legally own the stuff you post. For instance, when I rip the albums from our band and post them online, I can do so, I co-wrote/own the material. It's just like taping: mp3 can never sound as good as the real full cd. Impossible.

Good Luck!!

Comment: its not about ripping stuff off, i legally own these audio files and i would actually want to save money from EC2, hence the question on whether services like dropbox will work as src for audio

Comment: over a year later a sudden down-vote. No explanation. Seems like someone hates the concepts of free and sharing